# Is this Cauchy-Euler DIfferential Equation solvable using reduction of order, or by the general way to solve an Euler DE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I'm given this equation $$x^{2}y'' + xy' - y = 0$$ with the initial conditions $y(0)=0$ and $y'(0)=1$. By using the method normally used for Euler DE's, I get to the point where we have $$y(x) = c_{1}x + c_2x^{-1}$$
Except, this is where I'm getting confused, because obviously I can't divide by zero here, and even when I take the derivative, it's the same case, so I'm essentially not really getting any exact solution?

Am I missing something that we're supposed to do in cases like this? Or should I solve this by using a different method?

Comment: If the solution must be defined at $x=0$, then $y$ can only be in the form $y= c_1 x$.

Comment: Is there any reason why we're deciding this as the final answer? Even if it does have to be at $x=0$, why would we completely get rid of the $x^{-1}$ part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x^{2}y'' + xy' - y = 0$$
$$x^{2}y'' + 2xy'-xy' - y = 0$$
$$(x^2y')'-(xy)'=0$$
$$x(xy'-y)=C_1$$
$$y(0)=0,y'(0)=1 \implies C_1=0$$
$$xy'-y=0 \text { and } y(0)=0$$
For $y=0$ is not a solution since $$y'(0)=0 \ne 1$$
For $y \ne 0$:
$$\left (\dfrac x y\right)'=0$$
$$\dfrac xy=C_2$$
$$x=C_2y$$
$$y'(0)=1 \implies C_2 y'(0)=1 \implies C_2=1$$
$$y(x)=x$$

Comment: Hello. So this looks correct so thank you for showing this! However, can you explain why you solved the differential equation like this? Is this a particular method that I seem to be forgetting right now? How would you know to solve an equation this way?

Comment: Oh I see, that's interesting. Could you let me know where I can read more about this way of solving DE's? I want to read up on it a little bit if possible.